# React Router Authenticated Routes Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, amazon-cognito, react-router-v4

I'm trying to replicate the logic on the react-router website for [authenticating specific routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow).  For the most part it is working correctly but I appearing to be having an issue when checking whether the user is still authorized when the logic to determine it is asynchronous in nature.  Listed below is my component function for my private route.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    isAuthenticated() ? ( 
        <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login', 
            state: {from: props.location }
        }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

This logic calls into my isAuthenticated function which does an async call using Amazon Cognito and it always treats isAuthenticated as returning a false value even when I know it should be returning a true value.  The code for isAuthenticated is shown below:

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId : 'XXX', 
        ClientId : 'XXXX'
    };

    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

    if (cognitoUser != null) {
        cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
            if (err) {
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return session.isValid();
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I just hard code isAuthenticated to return a true or false value it works correctly in both situations.  My question is whether async logic is allowed in this context or if I should be determining the authentication state upstream of this logic.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact problem this morning (and even had to check to see if *I* had posted the question).

I took a hint from your question and moved the async "isAuthenticated" logic upstream to call ReactDom.render() two different ways depending on the user's local storage authentication result.

I'd be very interested in hearing from someone with a better solution, but my application can work this way.  Thanks for the idea!